# Div collapse after float css

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-float

I have a div called NAV and inside of NAV I have an UL with 5 li which I float to the left, the li's that is but when I do that the NAV collapses. I know this because I put a border around NAV to see if it collapses and it does.  Here is the example.

[collapsed http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/8867/collapsedze4.png](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/8867/collapsedze4.png)

[no collapsed http://img71.imageshack.us/img71/879/nocollapsedkx7.png](http://img71.imageshack.us/img71/879/nocollapsedkx7.png)

as you can see in the first image, the links in the NAV div are floated left and that
black border ontop is the actual div called NAV.

in this image you can see how it has top and bottom border and it not collapsed.

here is some of the html and css I used.

[alt text http://img301.imageshack.us/img301/5514/codejc8.png](http://img301.imageshack.us/img301/5514/codejc8.png)

```
#nav #ulListNavi  a  {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Where is the question? I found no question mark and failed to understand your question, if there is one.

Comment: While I got the answer I needed from this "question", I find confusing to read.

Answer (score 37):

Add any `overflow` value other than `visible` to your container:

```
div#nav { overflow:auto; }
```

Then add `width` to restore the width

```
div#nav { width: 100%; overflow:auto; }
```

Comment: This is the practice I have been using for a while and it seems to be the most elegant.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky - Nothing is perfect! Why not add your answer? But hurry, because the question has already been open for 3 and a half years...

Comment: @Ken So? I only found it now and would like other people who find it starting now to be aware of the issue, better late than never.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky Sorry, the 3 and a half years comment was more of a jab at user36682. But seriously, if you have a better answer you should add it (or edit my answer to improve it) - it's what this place is all about. :)

Answer (score 15):

One solution is to add a "clear:both" style to an element after the last floated anchor, for instance:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="ulListNavi">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Flowers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

This causes the containing element to clear all floating elements before closing the containing box.

Answer (score 5):

A few other options for clearing floats here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/02/26/simple-clearing-of-floats/

As to the best way of doing it, that's almost a holy war, the purists would freak about the extra div, if you are not fussed by a little extra markup, the addition of the cleared div as suggested by Joshua and AJ will work fine, and is a reliable technique, but there are at least 17 other ways of doing it...

Answer (score 4):

add this code after your ul:

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try floating the containing element to the left too.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with clearing elements or overflow. Add this:

```
#nav {
    float: left;
}
```

When you float the LI's, the #nav no longer "contains" anything so it collapses. But if the #nav is floated also, it contains anything floated inside it, so it expands again.

(Also consider removing the #nav div and just applying the same styles to the UL.)

Comment: This is the best answer. Only float the outer div. There is no reason to float the anchors. Though it is worth mentioning that the question does not illustrate the need to float anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because you are floating the `<A>` elements, but each of them is inside an `<LI>` element. `LI`s display as blocks by default, so each `<LI>` is forcing it's child `<A>` to begin on a new line.

If you float the `<LI>`s, I think you'll solve your problem.

```
#nav #ulListNavi  li  {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution would be to add overflow:hidden to clear the float on the parent element:

```
#nav{overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your HTML:

```
#nav
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
#ulListNavi
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav #ulListNavi li
{
    float: left;
}
#nav #ulListNavi li a
{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Works in IE8 and FF 3.5