# float:left for <li> creates spacing above navigation bar

Tags: css, navigationbar

Styling li tags with float:left is a standard way to create horizontal navigation bars.  But whenever I do this, the entire navigation bar list gets separated from the containing div.

Removing float:left would fix the problem, but let's assume I want to do it this way.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temp.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
  <h2>Demo: Navigation Bar</h2> 
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li>
      <a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#header {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 8in;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: auto; /* setting margin to auto centers block element */
    margin-right: auto; /* width must not be 100% */
}

#header ul { /* ul */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#header li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background-color: silver;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Edit:
Solution is to add empty div after the list, or style the containing div with overflow:hidden.

After looking for an explanation why this happens, I found a great link explaining everything!

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370432/div-collapse-after-float-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is, working with float's - use clearfixes. In your case, add the following, before header closing tag `</div>`:

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

That will make header strech, considering floating elements inside it.

Comment: Interesting.  How do you guys know this stuff? :)  Anyone care to explain why this happens?  Does the div tag ignore the last contained floating elements?

Comment: Floating elements has no bounding box, that is why those children LI, that are floating are ignored, by parent div bounding box. That style attribute, says, that it cant be floated around both sides, as it is after floating elements, it works like a marker, that is not ignored by parent div. Every page I develop, has class `.clearfix { clear: both; }` as it is used many times in page :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a div after the ul with style clear:left; - I would go into more detail, but I'm on my iPad and about to go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of anything in the li css code, put `#header li{display: inline;}` (and your color and other preferences)

Comment: Your answer looks like it's just an alternate to what was already answered in by the OP and the comment below it.  Great to answer, but just offer it up as an alternative rather than suggesting "instead".