# Testing for collapsed float

Tags: css, rspec, css-float

How do you test for a collapsed float, where a container element does not expand to take in floating elements, e.g. [Div collapse after float css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370432/div-collapse-after-float-css).

A collapsed float can be fixed by adding a css overflow:auto property to the container. However, if that overflow declaration is accidently deleted in a later edit, then the web page (or many pages if the container is used on many pages) can become unreadable.

Given that a collapsed float is not a CSS error and does not change the text on the page, how do you write a rspec test to detects if such a collapsed has occured?

Answer (score 0):

If you have items that are floated within an element, then you'll need to clear the float at the end.

```
.clearFloat {
    clear:both;
}
```

Here's a fiddle that shows what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/gMr9m/

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using capybara then if the collapsed float overlays element that is needed in your tests, then you will not be able to click on the hidden element.

So the good news is that if the collapsed float affects functionality, your tests should pick it up. If it just affects the look of the web site, then you will not. But then again, what good developer cares about aesthetics without function? :).